# Compare Date Time returned from API using only JavaScript and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, compare, comparison

I've got an API that returns me date time data like this:
"2021-09-29T08:00:00"
I want to filter those dates and return all the dates, before today.
I tested a function like this:

```js
  const currentDate = new Date();
  const results = licitacoes.map((item) => {
    const dateTime = new Date(item.licitacoesDate);
    if (currentDate < dateTime) {
      console.log("there are dateTime bigger than currentDate");
    } else {
      console.log("currentDate is bigger than DateTime");
    }
  });
```

That works fine inside my code. But what I really want is to display all the dates that are bigger than current date, when the user selects an input option.
So I tried this code here:

```js
 const currentDate = new Date();
 licitacoes.map((item) => {
       const dateTime = new Date(item.licitacoesDate);
      console.log(currentDate < dateTime)
    });
```

Which returns me false and give me a error, so I also tried this one:

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
licitacoes
      .filter((bigN) => new Date(bigN.licitacoesDate) < currentDate)
      .map((newNumber) => console.log(newNumber.cityName));
```

Which does not work if I test bigN.licitacoes.date > currentDate
And also returns me a giant error, but display the city names which are still available.
PS: This code will be displayed inside a if statement of a select button.

The licitacoes would be a json file like that:
licitacoes = [
{
"id": "1"
cityName: "London"
"licitacoesDate": "2021-04-05T08:00:00"
deliveryDate:"2021-05-12T08:00:00"
sourceUrl: "www.google.com"
licitacoesContent: "lorem ipsum"
}
]

Comment: you can do `dateTime - currentTime` and log it if it is greater than 0

Comment: Define "does not work". What is the "giant error"? Please provide sample data for *licitacoes* so that the code snippets display the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I'm gonna update the question with the licitacoes data. The console of Mozila was showing me lots of  different errors, but when I tried on the Chrome it showed only one, the error was: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, I think is: you don't have the data in your results? That is because you didn't return the value from map function, so all you need is return statement.

If you want to collect only `time` from `licitacoes`, you can do this:

```js
licitacoes = [ { "id": "1", cityName: "London", "licitacoesDate": "2021-04-05T08:00:00", deliveryDate:"2021-05-12T08:00:00", sourceUrl: "www.google.com",licitacoesContent: "lorem ipsum" } ]


const currentDate = new Date();
const dates = licitacoes.map((item) => {
    const dateTime = new Date(item?.licitacoesDate);
        if (currentDate > dateTime) {
            return item.licitacoesDate
        }

    });
console.log(dates)
```

better way is filter first then return value as you did:

```js
licitacoes = [ { "id": "1", cityName: "London", "licitacoesDate": "2021-04-05T08:00:00", deliveryDate:"2021-05-12T08:00:00", sourceUrl: "www.google.com",licitacoesContent: "lorem ipsum" } ]


const currentDate = new Date();
const dates = licitacoes
  .filter((bigN) => new Date(bigN.licitacoesDate) < currentDate)
  .map((newNumber) => newNumber.licitacoesDate);
console.log(dates)
```

If you want to return specific data you may do that:

```js
licitacoes = [ { "id": "1", cityName: "London", "licitacoesDate": "2021-04-05T08:00:00", deliveryDate:"2021-05-12T08:00:00", sourceUrl: "www.google.com",licitacoesContent: "lorem ipsum" } ]


const currentDate = new Date();
const dates = licitacoes
  .filter((bigN) => new Date(bigN.licitacoesDate) < currentDate)
  .map((data) => {
      return {
         time: data.licitacoesDate,
         city: data.cityName,
         sourceUrl: data.sourceUrl
              }
});
console.log(dates)
```

Or you can just filter `licitacoes` without `map`,  and it will return the array with all filtered items.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It worked fine! Can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: I want to collect the other data from the api that is also returned, like the cityName, or the content. Can you help me?

Comment: I've updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

- For bigger than current date: >
- .map() return Array, use forOf to show data.

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const filtered = licitacoes.filter((item) => new Date(item.licitacoesDate) > currentDate);
for(item of filtered){console.log(item.cityName)}
```

Comment: That is essentially what the OP is already doing but getting a "giant error".